Is the "assemble" a transitive or intransitive verb in "The shelves are easy to assemble"?
Is the "assemble" a transitive or intransitive verb in "The shelves are easy to assemble"?
There is seemingly no direct object for the "assemble" in "The shelves are easy to assemble", but it's stated as a transitive verb in the oxford dictionary...

@FumbleFingers Got it, thanks for your reply. For the additional example of dry, It's quick to dry this paint also works, right? So is it uncertain whether the dry is transitive or intransitive in This paint is quick to dry? A similar example is the tell in It's hard to tell.

It's quick to dry this paint could only be a transitive usage. It's unlikely, but in principle This paint is quick to dry could be transitive (you can quickly dry this paint). Normally we'd assume the intrasitive sense there, though - this paint (intransitively) dries itself. I see no possible context in which tell could be used intransitively in any such constructions.

Equally, This paint is quick to apply can only be a transitive usage, because although we can say intransitive This paint dries, we can't say This paint applies. There's a more complex construction involving adverbs whereby to some people, This paint applies quickly is acceptable, but not everyone endorses such forms, and they will only confuse you at your current level (others may wish to compare This wine is drinking well).

@FumbleFingers So for such constructions, is it true that intransitive will be prioritized, if possible? About the example of tell, please refer to [https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell?q=tell#:~:text=I%20think%20he%27s%20happy.%20It%27s%20hard%20to%20tell.] - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell?q=tell#:~:text=I%20think%20he%27s%20happy.%20It%27s%20hard%20to%20tell.

Obviously an imperative, @FumbleFingers? To me, what is obvious is that it’s a to-infinitive as in To assemble the shelves is easy. Nothing imperative about that, or about It is easy to assemble the shelves.

@FumbleFingers I can't see where you get this idea of an imperative in this sentence. It's far from obvious to me; would you explain what you you mean? As well, the transitiveness of "assemble" does not seem to be in question: there are two "assemble" essentially ("the children assemble in the courtyard", " they assembled the components"); it can't be the first.

@PaulTanenbaum, LPH: I can only imagine I had a "senior moment" there, because I'd just come from posting an answer about imperatives on ELL (and voting to migrate this question to ELL). I should have started with Obviously to assemble is intransitive in the cited context, and not included Equally obviously at the start of the second sentence. But you guys have made such a thing about it I'll leave the mistaken comment above.

@FumbleFingers Your answwer on ELL has nothing to do with to-infinitive clauses, and I can't see what  to-infinitive clauses  have  to do with the imperative mood.

@LPH: Jeez, what is this? The Spanish Inquisition? Okay, I won't leave the mistaken comment above. It's an ELL question anyway, and I doubt the comments would be usefully migrated if enough others agree with my vote to migrate it.

@FumbleFingers If you believe there is some ground for maintaining your claim, I have no objection to hearing what  made you think as you did; I'm only surprised by it. I agree with you as far as the difficulty of the answer goes (there is not much of a bone of contention in it, although I find the subtlety pointed out by the OP worth of consideration).

@LPH: I don't know what you're getting at. The OP here says There is seemingly no direct object for the "assemble" in "The shelves are easy to assemble", but it's stated as a transitive verb in the oxford dictionary. That's a very basic misunderstanding, since obviously the implied object of assemble is the shelves. It's certainly not "a subtlety"! That's why the question should be migrated to ELL. And I still think my point about true intransitive usages like This wine is drinking well is way beyond this OP's ability to understand at this stage in the learning process.

@FumbleFingers The point is that the construction does show the typical use of the transitive verb, as in "they assembled the shelves", but this transitive relation is not explicit either in "the shelves were assembled by them"; in the active-passive verb correspondence the nature of the verb does not change: it remains transitive and the object becomes the subject; that is all. Such utterances as "The wine is drinking well" and "the paper reads well" are a bit different, I think; there a redefinition of the verb, which makes it significantly different in meaning.

Victor: Re is it true that intransitive will be prioritized, if possible?, that's not a useful question to ask, and a yes/no answer will not help you learn English. The "preferred, prioritized" interpretation will be the one that makes most sense in the specific context. In principle a painter could dry his paint quicker using a hot air blower, but we prioritize the intransitive sense because usually the painter just leaves the paint to "dry itself". With some "same but different" example sentence, we might prioritize the transitive interpretation because it makes more sense.

This is just a comment, pointing out an interesting way of expressing this type of relation  between active verb and a noun, as in the example.  French uses à and an infinitive: facile à assembler.  Greek uses a noun phrase: 'easy in/for assembly (efkolo sti  synarmologisi - ευκολο στη συναρμολογηση).  Latin uses a rare noun formed from the verb, the 'supine', famously "mirabile visu".  Is it possible that each language has a different short cut so that we can keep the object of interest as subject of the sentence even though it is the object of an action? It works because it's obvious.

@FumbleFingers I could see what you mean - since obviously the implied object of assemble is the shelves, but do "The wine is drinking well" and "the paper reads well" (mentioned by @LPH) have their implied objects considering that both drink and read have transitive and intransitive senses in this context, why or why not?

@VictorLi: "The wine is drinking well" and "the paper reads well" don't have any objects (implied or explicit), because they're intransitive constructions. But as I pointed out before, constructions like that are not appropriate areas of study for your current skill level in English, so I suggest you don't waste time on them. I was simply making a peripheral point to LPH.


The shelves are easy to assemble

exemplifies what is known as tough movement in formal grammar:

In formal syntax, tough movement refers to sentences in which the
syntactic subject of the main verb is logically the object of an
embedded non-finite verb. Because the object of the lower verb is
absent, such sentences are also sometimes called "missing object
constructions".
The term tough movement reflects the fact that the prototypical
example sentences in English involve the word tough.
Examples:
In (1) and (2), the (a) examples illustrate tough movement in English.
In (1a) 'this problem' is logically the object of solve, and (1a) can be
paraphrased as (1b) or (1c).
In (2a) 'Chris' is logically the object of please, and (2a) can be
paraphrased as (2b) or (2c).

1a.  This problem is tough to solve.

1b.  It is tough to solve this problem

1c.  To solve this problem is tough.

2a.  Chris is easy to please.

2b.  It is easy to please Chris.

2c.  To please Chris is easy.                                                                       [Wikipedia]



The (b) and (c) paraphrases show that 'solve' and 'please' definitely carry a direct object ('this problem' and 'Chris').
But as stated, the object of the lower verb ('solve' and 'please', and 'assemble' in the example in the question) is absent after tough movement, now appearing as the syntactic subject of the main verb ('be' in all three examples here). One would have to invoke the missing object to claim that 'solve' / 'please' / 'assemble' are transitive in sentences exhibiting tough movement. Probably time has been wasted by linguists debating the issue.

This is a case of adjective complementatrion (A Comprehensive Grammar of the English language, Quirk et al, 1985).

(CoGEl § 16.68) Adjective complementation
Categories of complementation in adjective phrases […] are
similar in variety to those of verb complementation. We distinguish [E1-E5]
as follows :
[El] Complementation by a prepositional phrase
[E21 Complementation by a that-clause
[E31 Complementation by a wh-clause
[E41 Complementation by a than-clause
[E51 Complementation by a to-infinitive clause
[E61 Complementation by an -ing participle clause
[…]


(CoGEL § 16.75) [E5] Adjective complementation by a to-infinitive clause
We distinguish seven kinds of construction in which an adjective is followed
by a to-infinitive clause. They are exemplified in the following sentences,
which are superficially alike:

Bob is splendid to wait.
Bob is slow to react.
Bob is sorry to hear it.
Bob is hesitant to agree with you.
Bob is hard to convince.
The food is ready to eat.
It is important to be accurate.

In Types 1-4 the subject of the main clause (Bob) is also the subject of the infinitive clause. We can therefore always have a direct object in the infinitive clause if its verb is transitive. For example, if we replace intransitive wait by transitive build in 1, we can have: Bob is splendid to build this house.
For Types 5-7, on the other hand, the subject of the infinitive is
unspecified, although the context often makes clear which subject is intended.
In these types it is possible to insert a subject preceded by for; eg in Type
(6): The food is ready (for the children) to eat.



Is "assemble" a transitive or intransitive verb in
"The shelves are easy to assemble"?


"Assemble" is transitive in this sentence. The construction can be identified with "5" above, where the verb is transitive, and where the subject of the infinitive is unspecified. So, it is this particular type of complementation construction for the adjective that we are dealing with here that is responsible for obfuscating (to a point) the usually explicitly apparent relation of transitivity ("you assemble the shelves, the shelves are assembled by you" (not so explicit in this latter example)).
Complement
Transitivity does not appear to be a description of the construction in which a verb is used but rather an intrinsic property that can be ignored in certain conditions.

(Copilot)
"Absolute transitive verb" is a term used to describe a verb that is typically transitive (requiring a direct object) but that is used without a direct object in a particular clause. In such cases, the verb is considered to be used “absolutely” or intransitively. For example, in the sentence “He eats,” the verb “eats” is typically transitive (as in “He eats an apple”), but here it is used without a direct object.

Thus we can say that the verb is used intransitively or absolutely, but its lexical category is unchanged.

Thanks for your reply. Is the wait transitive or intransitive in Bob is splendid to wait, given that Bob waited others and Bob waited outside all work?

But Bob waited others doesn't work, except in a really weird context and domain-specific usage involving Bob the waiter in a restaurant. And Bob is splendid to wait is an unlikely utterance from a native Anglophone today. You really should be asking questions like this on English Language Learners

@VictorLi In fact, that particular case, is, as far as goes my apprehension of idiomatic English, a limit case: personally I wouldn't use it. I'd rather say "It's very nice from Bob to be waiting on us.", or something like that, and that is what it means, bar the theatrical "illumination", which is the idea of what "splendid" confers to me  when I think really about it (old fashioned: very good") . // This being said, "wait" is intransitive  ("wait on us, wait for us", "just wait").

It's very nice from Bob to be waiting on us is most definitely not idiomatically valid. The most natural version is It's very nice of Bob to wait for us (unless Bob's a waiter).

@FumbleFingers Agreed, I have no notion of "waiting on people*" as used without a complement ("she would not  wait" seems incorrect, whereas ""she would not wait on people" has to be).  there is no problem with "waiting for somebody".

Well, AmE (not so much BrE) allows He's waiting on us instead of ...for us to mean We're keeping him waiting, but so far as I know there's no dialectal variant within which anything could be very nice from Bob [to do something]. That one's always nice of Bob.

I'm just waiting on a friend. But maybe the Stones were speaking AmE in that song.

@PeterShor: You're American, which proves my point. But would you yourself always use on rather than for in such contexts?

@FumbleFingers: I'd always use for, but that's just because I grew up in Washington D.C. and California, and not near New York City. (I lived near NYC for nearly two decades later in life, so I'm also accustomed to hearing waiting on.)

@PeterShor: Oh, I didn't realize it might reflect an East-West divide within the US. Is there any chance things like that reflect greater influence from AAVE and/or Yiddish in NYC, as opposed to the greater influence of Spanish in California?

@FunmbleFingers ... actually, it's a North/South divide. People in the South say "waiting on"; everybody else says "waiting for". I got confused with "waiting on line" in my previous comment, that only people form New York say.

@FumbleFingers Maybe Bob waited other students instead of Bob waited others could make it more clear. What I mean is that how to tell the transitivity of wait in Bob is splendid to wait when the "wait" can be a transitive and intransitive verb in dictionary.

@FumbleFingers I just went back though the comments, and caught your remark concerning "from". Your pointing out  this error  makes me suddenly conscious of the fact the preposition couldn't be anything else than "of".
